# Advanced Installer single EXE setup MSI file name

Tags: build, configuration, windows-installer, exe, advanced-installer

UPD: Actual answer to my problem is in second comment by @CMk under the original answer.

I have searched for solution across tutorials and StackOverflow with no result.

I'm generating a setup package with Advanced Installer and when Single EXE (resources inside) type is selected, MSI file has a random name generated, inside the package.
Is there any way to control the name of that file, while packaging? Setting name for MSI in Build Settings section does not affect the file name in the package, only if I generate actual "Single MSI" type, which is not what I need.

Thanks!

I have searched for solution across tutorials and StackOverflow with no result.
Looked at settings available in the Advanced Installer.

Update after @CMk answer:

I probably had to be more clear regarding the issue.
When installation is in progress and there is a window asking permission to perform operations on the disk. A MSI filename is mentioned there:
[Naming issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CePSq.jpg)
This file name is always in this form despite the fact that in settings shown on the picture in the answer, names are all set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this just now and it looks like if you manually input the name for the MSI in the builds page, when the EXE setup extracts it, it will have that name.

[image: BuildsPage]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I have updated description of the issue with more details.

Comment: Thank you for the followup on this! It looks like I misunderstood your question.

Please make sure to have the "Description" (from the "Digital Signature" page) field set to the name you want to be displayed, otherwise it will have a random name when the UAC appears. In this field, you can use something like [|ProductName].

Comment: !!! So here where it gets the name from. Thanks!
It is seems quite un-logical to me (as it is an MSI file after all), but it works.